# To hide "#" from the URL using Nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am using Nginx web server to host my website. I need to hide "#" from URL.

Actual: example.com/#page2
Requirement: example.com/page2

Our web page developer says that, here #page2 is defined as id in the index.html file (so that when we call example.com/#page2 it will navigate to the page2 part, which is available in same page)

Kindly suggest & thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve with this? Anchors have a purpose ... If you want have stuff in separate files, then put it there, not all in one...

Comment: The fragment part of the URL isn't sent to the server, so there's no way for you to see if the fragment is present or not. You'll have to use client-side code for this. JavaScript [`history.pushState` and/or `history.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) are useful for this, but aren't supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK (but please don't take this for granted), these anchors are processed by the client, and not sent to the webserver. If this is true, you can't alter these via nginx. If you absolutely have to (but again: what's the point of this?), you need to do this at the client side, via JavaScript for example.

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at nginx rewrite rules.

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/variables_in_config.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html

The `rewrite` directive might solve your problem. For a more specific answer more information is necessary.

Comment: Which information are you missing, to be more specific?